# ¿como hacer correctamente un ping en php?

Tags: php

actualmente ando construyendo una herramienta para testear la disponibilidad de un sitio web, lo ando haciendo en php y funciona de maravilla

```
<?php
function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    $file      = @fsockopen ($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file) $status = -1;  // Site is down
    else {
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }

    if ($status <> -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
//llamando a la funcion
if (pingDomain('www.dominio.com')) {
    echo 'ON';
} else {
    echo 'OFF';
}
```

pero como verán solo funciona con sitios

> www.dominio.com

pero no me funciona con directorios,

> www.dominio.com/seccionaparte

que cambios podría realizar para que pueda testear ese tipo de url? gracias de antemano

si es mas fácil con otro lenguaje acepto sugerencias...

Comment: Fsockopen abre conexiones sobre el host asociado, no sobre un recurso de ese dominio. Lo que puedes hacer es abrir un file_get_contents una vez comprobado el dominio, si puedes abrirlo es que existe

Comment: creo q tienes razón a lo que comentas. es que esos directorio tienen diferentes lands pages y a veces se cae la base de datos por el alto trafico y quisiera estar alertado de esas incidencias, el file_get seria de ayuda? alguna documentacion para leela?. gracias

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php